# SQL SELECT logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been having a bit of trouble thinking this problem through. I can't seem to define a SELECT query which is accurate enough to give me the result I want.

I am storing shift patterns in a table. These shift patterns don't have any restrictions on when they can start and finish (except that they cannot overlap each other per machine)

*This is the structure of the table (5 rows of example data)*
[image: Table]

The only information I have to select with is:

- The current time (e.g. 01:45)
- The current weekday (e.g. Tuesday)

The issue is when a shift overlaps 00:00. So my question is this:

**How would I select the current shift based on the current time and weekday?**

[Here is an SQL Fiddle of the scenario](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68aba0/2)

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Stop using `VARCHAR` for all columns. Use `TINYINT` for weekdays and `TIME` for time columns. 2. Please include code from sqlfiddle over into your post.

Comment: Are you stuck with this terrible table schema, or can you change it?

Comment: Do you have any control over what's in the table or must you use what's here?  Also will a shift ever run over more than one day (e.g. Monday to Wednesday)?

Comment: Are there any shifts between Friday and Monday?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - I can change it if needed what would you suggest?

Comment: Or rather, simply use `DATETIME` column and you'll only need two columns. A. `Start` and B. `End`

Comment: What @hjpotter92 just said.  You can use the 'datetime` data type, since you are trying to represent dates and times.  `varchar` is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: @EliGassert - Yes shifts can run over days (see ShiftName C) That's actually the problem, because when a shift overlaps a day there isn't any way for me to specify what shift it currently is (which is what I'm trying to return)

Comment: I know it can run Monday to Tuesday.  Can it run over Monday to Wednesday?  Run over one day vs multiple days?

Comment: Is it Ok if I give you TSQL and you convert it into MySQL?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - These aren't specific dates though, doesn't a DATETIME have to contain an actual set date? Like I just want to say: on Monday at 17:00 where are in Shift B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with simple logic.  If `StartTime < EndTime`, then you want to test for times between the two values.  If `Startime > EndTime`, then you want to test for times *not* between the two values.  So this solves the time problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM webreportshiftsetup
WHERE (StartTime < EndTime and time(now()) between StartTime and EndTime or
       StartTime > EndTime and time(now()) not between StartTime and EndTime
      ) and
      dayname(now()) in (StartWeekDay, EndWeekDay)
```

You have a similar problem with the weekdays.  But your question is specifically about times and not weekdays. (That should perhaps be another question.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answers. This answer got me the closest! (I have had discussions with our client, and they are prepared to upload a yearly shift schedule to the database, which makes this entire process a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

If your shifts are one-day (i.e. you need to select only current day) you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM shifts
WHERE startWeekDay = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%W') AND NOW() BETWEEN startTime AND endTime
```

Otherwise, if your shift starts on Monday and finishes on Wednesday, and today is Tuesday, you will have trouble finding todays shift with a query. For that you should store days as number: 1- Monday, 2- Friday, ...

Comment: I am able to store the days as numbers, I can change the schema as I see fit. I have done that and I'm still coming across the same problem because the only data I have to select with is the current time and current day of week (which will be a number, but isn't it effectively the same problem?)

Comment: Well it is the same problem if your shifts start and end on the same day, but if you have a shift that starts on Monday and ends on Friday, and today is day in between, it is much easier to find the correct shift. Do you have shifts that start on one day and end on another?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change the schema.  One option is to use the `datetime` type for start/end, instead of using varchar for everything.

Then you can query it like:

```
SELECT *
FROM webreportshiftsetup
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN StartDateTime AND EndDateTime
```

and so forth.

If you need this to be a repeating thing to where specific dates won't work, then you might make the StartDay/EndDay columns `tinyint` and give them a value of 1-7, with the smallest number being the first day of the week and the largest number representing the last day of the week.  StartTime/EndTime would be `date` type.  Querying that would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM webreportshiftsetup
WHERE StartDay >=2 AND EndDay <=4 AND StartTime >= '2:00' AND EndTime <= '13:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah it is a repeating set of data (well, its basically a setup table that _defines_ the shift pattern over 7 days). That is what is causing the issue basically, since I cant say BETWEEN Start & End